# Updating Array Value in For Loop Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, pointers, for-loop, counter

I'm interested in updating an array element value within a for loop, but my update definition is wrong, since the output contain `[counter]`. 
Here is the code I have:

```
declare -a mem_set=(0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
counter=0
for i in "${domain_path[@]}"
do
    cd $i
    echo "$(pwd)"
    for mLine in $(grep 'default.default.minmaxmemory.main' start_params.properties)
    do
            echo "$mLine"
    done
    l_bound="Xmx"
    r_bound="m"
    mem_set[counter]=$(echo "$mLine" | sed -e "s/.*${l_bound}//;s/${r_bound}.*//")
    echo "$mem_set[counter]"
    let counter=counter+1
done
```

The loop and the `$(echo "$mLine" | sed -e "s/.*${l_bound}//;s/${r_bound}.*//")` run fine, but I can't manage to get the right output. What is my update statement is missing? The output of it is `2048[counter]`. Also, instead of using another counter `counter` in addition to `i`, is it possible to use `i` for `mem_set` array as well (both arrays have the same size)?

Thank you

Comment: can you change `echo "$mem_set[counter]"` to `echo "${mem_set[counter]}"` and see if that prints out the right value?

Comment: Your inner for loop is identical to `grep 'def...main' start_params.properties`.

Comment: @ravoori thank you for your suggestion. Changing the format worked, so now I get the right output.

Comment: @ravoori another quick question, if I want to use the same array element in an if statement, should it be in the same format? e.g. `if [ "${mem_set[counter]" -ne "${mem_set[7]}" ]; then ....`

Answer (score 0):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

can you change echo "$mem_set[counter]" to echo "${mem_set[counter]}" and see if that prints out the right value? –  1_CR

thank you for your suggestion. Changing the format worked, so now I get the right output. –  Simply_Me

Answer (score -1):

In bash, you would access a variable with $.

Try,

```
counter=`expr $counter + 1`
```

or

```
counter=$(( counter + 1 ))
```